# Keys cannot be added to keystore

Tags: private-network, key, tutorials

**Problem**

Keys cannot be added to keystore.

**Situation description**

To launch the private network, the boot node was first started and succeeded.[❶]
The next time I tried to add a keys to the keystore I got the following error.[❷]

Tutorial URL
[enter link description here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/#Start-the-blockchain-using-predefined-accounts)

**Error**

-bash: version: No such file or directory

**Execution environment**

mamOS Big Sur version 11.3.1
Macbook Air（M1, 2020）

**Commands executed in the terminal**

❶Start the first node[succeeded]

./target/release/node-template 
--base-path /tmp/node01 
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json 
--port 30333 
--ws-port 9945 
--rpc-port 9933 
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" 
--validator 
--rpc-methods Unsafe 
--name MyNode01

❷Add keys to the keystore[error]

./target/release/node-template key insert
--base-path /tmp/node01 
--chain customSpecRaw.json 
--scheme Sr25519 
--suri your-secret-seed 
--password-interactive 
--key-type aura

※The your-secret-seed section has been changed.

**Research**

■Location where the command was executed

/Users/username/Substrate/substrate-node-template

■Path to Key Store

/private/tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore

**Questionable points.**

【--base-path /tmp/node01 \】

Even though the boot node was able to run[❶], why does it show no files or directories when I add a keys[❷], as the above error indicates?
Is there a problem with the path that prevents adding keys? If so, why was the boot node able to run?

Comment: Are you sure /private/tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore is corect? Then the base path should be /private/tmp/node01

Answer (score 1):

`--base-path /tmp/node01` does not seem to match the path you want which is `/private/tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore`.

So maybe just update your `base-path` path.

Or maybe just `mkdir /tmp/node01`?